# User Account Management URL structure

Tags: urls

What is the clearest, most logical way to lay out user account management url structure?  For example:

1. /users/login
2. /users/(signup|sign-up)
3. /users/myaccount/(edit)
4. /users/username/(edit)
5. /users/(my)account

These are just some possibilities, I am not worried so much about SEO unless it is "deal breaker" of sorts (which I doubt).  I'd like to also know if there is not much of an importance to a specific url structure, and maybe we can be creative with branding URLs like /mygolfcart and so forth.

Comment: This is relevant -- http://blog.moustach.io/post/13232995421/use-sign-in-rather-than-log-in

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I quite like using /account/ as the prefix, like this...

- Log in: **/account/login**
- My account: **/account** (redirects to /account/login if not logged in)
- Log out: **/account/logout**
- Sign up: **/account/create** or **/account/signup**
- Change password: **/account/password**

I think this is a good structure since it organises the URLs from the user's perspective, instead of from the developer's perspective (as is the case with the /users/ prefix).

Comment: +1 for "organises the URLs from the user's perspective, instead of from the developer's perspective".  To @Anthony, bear in mind that for the user, the path to their information would most likely be by bookmark or clearly visible link, and only thirdly (if at all) by memory of the URL structure.  Not to say that visible URL structure isn't important (it is) but not to forget the first two...

Comment: So is there any empirical data on /account vs another more "user friendly" url structure, or is that somewhat negligible as long as its clear?

Comment: None that I know of, however it's certainly best to do things from the user's perspective if possible.

Answer (score 0):

A simple URL/login will do and you can **show your creativity inside the page** where the user is going to see your product.

URL should be user friendly so that they remember next time easily. So I believe if its a *login page* , the User dont have to remember this as this is one time thing.